# Default route is for the wrong router on same network

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, router

This is just plain bizarre, I really am not sure what to make of it.

The router situation of the place I'm staying at is as follows: there is a wireless router (router A) that is connected directly to the ISP (router provided by ISP), however its range is rather limited so there's another wireless router upstairs (router B) which is connected to router A.

Each of these routers has their own SSID. I'm downstairs, and upon selecting to connect to router A everything seems to work fine - the graphical indication is that the connection is strong and functioning. But what's this, I can't access anything online? Wondering if it's an issue with the network itself, I check if anyone else is having problems - my sister's apple thingy is functioning properly, so it's not an issue with the internet connection. Puzzled, I attempt to access the router page, and here's where things get really weird: I access the connection information, look up the default route (192.168.1.1, in case you were wondering), and enter it into firefox. And it gives me the router page... for router B (I can tell because I've looked at the router pages for both routers before, and they're from different vendors). I double check, triple check, quadruple check that it indicates that I am connected to router A. The connection name indicated is for router A. Puzzled, I try restarting network-manager - my go-to solution for network stuff randomly breaking - but it doesn't change anything. I reboot the computer. Same problem. I try disabling the connection to router B. Same problem.

The good news is that eventually, I just turned off router B and everything started working like it was supposed to. But I am really, *really* confused as to what was happening. How can that even happen?

Background information dump:

OS: Lubuntu 15.10 32-bit (x86)
Network card: Broadcom BCM4311
Machine model: Dell Latitude D630

This system has been able to connect just fine to all other networks, including both router A and B the last time I was here.

How can something like that happen? I'm not always going to be able to control which wireless routers are available, and it really bugs me that this madness is possible.

I'm looking for:

1. A possible explanation for the behavior. I'd believe just about anything at this point.
2. Information about how to attempt to track down the cause of this behavior.
3. In the event that this is a bug, where would this be reported? The driver? Network Manager?

Apologies in advance if I've missed something obvious.